# How to import data from viewcontroller to shopping cart TableView

Tags: ios, swift

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LavF.png)  is my previous view controller
I am trying to import the data from it into [this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhACQ.png)

Here is my first ViewController code (it's ss is not given) :

```
import UIKit
struct jsonstruct: Codable {
    let name: String
    let catalog_visibility: String
    let short_description: String
    let description: String
    let price: String
    let categories: [Categories]
    let images: [Images]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case catalog_visibility
        case short_description
        case description
        case price
        case categories
        case images
    }
}

struct Categories: Codable {
    let type: String
    
    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "name"
    }
}

struct Images: Codable {
    let src: String
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var searchbar: UISearchBar!
    
    var imgdata = [Images]()
    
    var categorydata = [Categories]()
    
    var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchbar.endEditing(true)
        getdata()
               
    }
    @IBAction func cartBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let detail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail!, animated: true)
    }
    func getdata() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://mywebstaging.net/ab/garnier/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_4a6a758693004efa43ad311d18b30461e6a03d1f&consumer_secret=cs_41a3324c8f8e950ca75764872ae91ea4e5c9b85b")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do{if error == nil{
                self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct].self, from: data!)

                    print(self.arrdata)
                    //print(self.arrdata[0].categories.name)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            
            }catch{
                print("Error in get json data")
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return arrdata.count
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
        cell?.img.downloadImage(from: (self.arrdata[indexPath.item].images.first?.src)!)
        cell?.lblName.text = arrdata[indexPath.row].name
        cell?.lblSHDesc.text = arrdata[indexPath.row].categories.first?.type
        cell?.lblDesc.text = arrdata[indexPath.row].short_description
        cell?.lblPrice.text = arrdata[indexPath.row].price
        return cell!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
        
        if let urlString = arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    detail?.Image = UIImage(data: data)!
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        detail?.Name = arrdata[indexPath.row].name
        detail?.Name2 = arrdata[indexPath.row].name
        detail?.SH_desc = arrdata[indexPath.row].categories.first!.type
        detail?.Desc = arrdata[indexPath.row].description
        detail?.Price = arrdata[indexPath.row].price

        let imagesArray = arrdata[indexPath.row].images

        if imagesArray.count > 0, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[0].src) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    detail?.Img1 = UIImage(data: data)!
                }
            }.resume()
        }
            
        if imagesArray.count > 1, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[1].src) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    detail?.Img2 = UIImage(data: data)!
                }
            }.resume()
        }
            
        if imagesArray.count > 2, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[2].src) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    detail?.Img3 = UIImage(data: data)!
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail!, animated: true)
    }
}
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Below is my code for DetailViewController :

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
    
    var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
    var categorydata = [Categories]()
    var imgdata = [Images]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var prodName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var probName2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodSHDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var probImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var ratingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var addToCartbtn: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var one: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var two: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var three: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var imgone: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgtwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgthree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var cart4View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cartCount: UILabel!
    
    
    var Image = UIImage()
    var Name = ""
    var Name2 = ""
    var SH_desc = ""
    var Desc = ""
    var Price = ""
    var Img1 = UIImage()
    var Img2 = UIImage()
    var Img3 = UIImage()
    

    var callback : ((Int)->())?
    var counter1 = 0 {
          didSet {
            cartCount.text = "\(counter1)"
          }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        probImage.image = Img1
        
        probImage.image = Image
        prodName.text = Name
        probName2.text = Name2
        prodSHDesc.text = SH_desc
        prodDesc.text = Desc
        prodPrice.text = Price
        imgone.image = Img1
        imgtwo.image = Img2
        imgthree.image = Img3
    }
    
    @IBAction func firstImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img1
    }
    
    @IBAction func secondImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img2
    }
    
    @IBAction func thirdImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img3
    }
    
    @IBAction func cartTappedToNavigate(_ sender: Any) {
        let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        showAlert()
        counter1 += 1
        callback?(counter1)
        (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
        addToCartbtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Item Added to Cart", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
   
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Here is the code for CartViewController :

```
import UIKit

class CartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
    var categorydata = [Categories]()
    var imgdata = [Images]()
    
    @IBOutlet var cartTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet var totalCount: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var proceedBtn: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet var subtotalPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var shippingPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalPrice: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrdata.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCellTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CartCellTableViewCell

        return cell!
    }
    
}
```

Here is the code for cellCartViewControllerCell :

```
import UIKit

class CartCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var cartImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var productNameCart: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var prodductDescCart: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var productPriceCart: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var subBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var prodCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addBtn: UIButton!
    
    var callback : ((Int)->())?
    var counter1 = 0 {
          didSet {
            prodCount.text = "\(counter1)"
          }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    @IBAction func subBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if counter1 > 0 { counter1 -= 1 }
        callback?(counter1)
    }
    
    @IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        counter1 += 1
        callback?(counter1)
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

Now I am confused how to pass data from detailVewController to cartTableView while adding items to the cart. please help me out! Thanks in advance..

UPDATE: This is my code now for DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

struct CartStruct: Codable {
    let cartItems: [jsonstruct?]
    let cartQuantity: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cartItems
        case cartQuantity
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var categorydata = [Categories]()
    var imgdata = [Images]()

    var detailInfo = [jsonstruct?]()
    var cartArray = [CartStruct]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var prodName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var probName2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodSHDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var probImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var ratingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var addToCartbtn: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var one: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var two: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var three: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var imgone: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgtwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imgthree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var cart4View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cartCount: UILabel!
    
    
    var Image = UIImage()
    var Name = ""
    var Name2 = ""
    var SH_desc = ""
    var Desc = ""
    var Price = ""
    var Img1 = UIImage()
    var Img2 = UIImage()
    var Img3 = UIImage()
    

    var callback : ((Int)->())?
    var counter1 = 0 {
          didSet {
            cartCount.text = "\(counter1)"
          }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        probImage.image = Img1
        
        probImage.image = Image
        prodName.text = Name
        probName2.text = Name2
        prodSHDesc.text = SH_desc
        prodDesc.text = Desc
        prodPrice.text = Price
        imgone.image = Img1
        imgtwo.image = Img2
        imgthree.image = Img3
    }
    
    @IBAction func firstImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img1
    }
    
    @IBAction func secondImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img2
    }
    
    @IBAction func thirdImgBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        probImage.image = Img3
    }
    
    @IBAction func cartTappedToNavigate(_ sender: Any) {
        let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let info = detailInfo {
            cartArray.append(CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1))
            cartCount.text = "\(cartArray.count)"
            showAlert()
            (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
            addToCartbtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }       
    }
    
    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Item Added to Cart", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
   
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you storing your cart data? If app kills or update, how you are handling your cart data? are you removing all?

Comment: I am not being able to insert data into the cart when I click "add to cart" button in the 'detailViewController'

Comment: where you want to store? Is in local DB or just temporal?

Comment: At first I want to display the porductname, productimage, productprice etc into the cart whenever that product is added to cart.

Comment: check and let me know.

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: You are not passing your selection instance from "ViewController" Just follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024118/6681858, Next add todays code from answer, I'm not able to edit your question.

Comment: Here the line of code " detail?.detailInfo = arrdata[indexPath.row] " was showing error like  " Cannot assign value of type 'jsonstruct' to type '[jsonstruct]'  " ...   So I avoided this part

Comment: Abdul Hoque Nuri
not working.. please check in GitHub. I have uploaded the project.  https://github.com/webgrityahana/GarnierShop-2-4

Answer (score 0):

The cart place is the ViewController. Other views should access the cart via method declared in a protocole cartManager (allitems. Add item,…)
the protocole is implemented by the view controller to update the cart and to send its contents to the objects which want. Each of this object should have a cartManager property which is instanciated after the controller creation from storyboard.
Then these objects just call the property with the method they need.

Comment: please guide me how to import data into the tableview of cart page..?

Answer (score 0):

Store cart item in an Array, Next Pass it to your cart controller.

1. Add below code in **DetailViewController**

   ```
    struct CartStruct {
    var cartItems: YourJSONDataStruct
    var cartQuantity: Int
    }

    var detailInfo: YourJSONDataStruct
    var cartArray = [CartStruct]()
   ```

   class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

   ```
    @IBAction func cartTappedToNavigate(_ sender: Any) {
        let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
        cart?.cartArray = cartArray
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let info = detailInfo {
            cartArray.append(CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1))
            cartCount.text = "\(cartArray.count)"
            showAlert()
            addToCartbtn.setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
            addToCartbtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Item Added to Cart", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }}
   ```

Next, Display cart in your CartViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

var cartArray = [CartStruct]()
var categorydata = [Categories]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cartArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CartCellTableViewCell
    cell.cartImageView.downloadImage(from: cartArray[indexPath.row].cartItems.images.first?.src ?? "place_holder_image")
    cell.productNameCart.text = cartArray[indexPath.row].cartItems.name
    cell.prodductDescCart.text = cartArray[indexPath.row].cartItems.shortDescription
    cell.productPriceCart.text = cartArray[indexPath.row].cartItems.price
    cell.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(add(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.addBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    let cartQuantity = cartArray[indexPath.row].cartQuantity
    cell.prodCount.text = "\(cartQuantity)"
    if cartQuantity > 1 {
        cell.subBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        cell.subBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sub(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.subBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    } else {
        cell.subBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
    }
    return cell
}

@objc func add(sender: UIButton){
    if cartArray[sender.tag].cartQuantity > 0 {
        cartArray[sender.tag].cartQuantity += 1
        cartTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@objc func sub(sender: UIButton){
    if cartArray[sender.tag].cartQuantity >= 1 {
        cartArray[sender.tag].cartQuantity -= 1
        cartTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: please check my ans. and plz help me to resolve the error!

Comment: @AhanaChakraborty commented on your answer.